# Border is not getting displayed in Flex Searchable ComboBox after selecting an item

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Just after choosing an item in Searchable ComboBox, the border of the combobox is not visible. Then on blur of the combox the border is again visible. It's really strange feeling. Please help me out here.

```
<ComboBox id="studyId" 
     dataProvider="{employeeList}" 
/>
```

Here employeeList is an ArrayList collection where employee objects are there. 
Note: I cannot provide/change any css/style for this combobox. Please let me know if there is any other way in mxml part or Action Script.

The combobox looks like the image.[image]

Comment: Does it use any custom skin classes? Try to set styleName="" so it will switch to the default skin class - just to see if the problem disappears. If so, the problem is likely to be in the custom skin class. If you have no access to any css or skin classes maybe you can do your own for this specific combobox. Another posibility is that it uses some custom item renderers that might overlap the border?

Comment: There is custom skin class but I am not authorized to change that file and there is no custom item renders for it. May be if there is any possibility to fix it using ActionScript or Flex side.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, its because of using application wide theme style since there is no skin associated with this combobox component.

The best way to handle this is by creating custom skin in Flex to override any style you need.

Example: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/11/removing-the-vertical-separator-from-the-halo-combobox-control-in-flex-4/

Hope this helps.